# How to make different type for a JavaScript Class in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I want to do something like `Map<string, number>` and `Map<string, string>` using JSDoc without TypeScript. How?

```js
class MyValue {
  setValue(value){
     this.myValue = value;
  }
  getValue(){
     return this.myValue;
  }
}


/* @type { MyValue<number> } */
const a = new MyValue();
a.setValue(123);
const av = a.getValue(); // How to use JSDoc to make bv become number automatically?

/* @type { MyValue<string> } */
const b = new MyValue();
b.setValue('456');
const bv = b.getValue(); // How to use JSDoc to make bv become string automatically?
```

JSDoc auto generate hints `av: number` and `bv: string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer in this question.

[JSDoc override return type of inherited class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72478343/jsdoc-override-return-type-of-inherited-class-method)

```js
    /**
    * MyValue
    * @class
    * @template T
    */
    class MyValue {

        /**
         * 
         * @param {T} value 
         */
        setValue(value) {
            this.myValue = value;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @returns {T}
         */
        getValue() {
            return this.myValue;
        }
    }
```